# linux for loop two variables each time

Tags: bash

I have several files in a directory and I want to run some linux packages on these files by every two of them, like ERR1045141_1 with ERR1045141_2 and ERR1045144_1 with ERR1045144_2 and so on. So I write a for loop for this but it is not working.

```
files:
ERR1045141_1.fastq.gz
ERR1045141_2.fastq.gz
ERR1045144_1.fastq.gz
ERR1045144_2.fastq.gz
ERR1045145_1.fastq.gz
ERR1045145_2.fastq.gz
ERR1045146_1.fastq.gz
ERR1045146_2.fastq.gz
ERR1045148_1.fastq.gz
ERR1045148_2.fastq.gz
ERR1045149_1.fastq.gz
ERR1045149_2.fastq.gz
ERR1045151_1.fastq.gz
ERR1045151_2.fastq.gz
ERR1045152_1.fastq.gz
ERR1045152_2.fastq.gz
ERR1045154_1.fastq.gz
ERR1045154_2.fastq.gz

codes:
files=ls
for (( i=0; i<${#files[@]} ; i+=2 )) ; do
echo "${files[i]}" "${files[i+1]}"
done
```

It did not work and I am not sure is the files=ls has something wrong.Or any better way to do it.please advise.

Comment: You just set `files` to the string `ls`. You meant `files=($(ls))`, but that's not a good idea either and breaks for files with special characters. You should use `files=(*)`, a glob.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following if you are sure about the existence of the second file:

```
for file1 in ERR*_1*
do
file2=`echo $file1 | sed 's/_1/_2/g'`
echo $file1 $file2
done
```

Answer (score 0):

No, what you *really* want to do is to process all the `1` files, performing some action on it and its associated `2` file.

You can do that with something as simple as the `for` loop in this complete test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

doSomethingWith() {
    echo "[$1] [$2]"
}

touch 'xERR1045141_1.fastq.gz' 'xERR1045141_2.fastq.gz'
touch 'xERR1045144_1.fastq.gz' 'xERR1045144_2.fastq.gz'
touch 'xERR1045145_1.fastq.gz' 'xERR1045145_2.fastq.gz'
touch 'xERR1045146_1.fastq.gz' 'xERR1045146_2.fastq.gz'
touch 'xERR1045148_1.fastq.gz' 'xERR1045148_2.fastq.gz'
touch 'xERR1045149_1.fastq.gz' 'xERR1045149_2.fastq.gz'
touch 'xERR1045151_1.fastq.gz' 'xERR1045151_2.fastq.gz'
touch 'xERR1045152_1.fastq.gz' 'xERR1045152_2.fastq.gz'
touch 'xERR1045154_1.fastq.gz' 'xERR1045154_2.fastq.gz'
touch 'xERR  45154_1.fastq.gz' 'xERR  45154_2.fastq.gz'

for file1 in xERR*_1.fastq.gz ; do
    file2="${file1/_1/_2}"
    doSomethingWith "${file1}" "${file2}"
done

rm -rf xERR*.fastq.gz
```

This program outputs:

```
[xERR1045141_1.fastq.gz] [xERR1045141_2.fastq.gz]
[xERR1045144_1.fastq.gz] [xERR1045144_2.fastq.gz]
[xERR1045145_1.fastq.gz] [xERR1045145_2.fastq.gz]
[xERR1045146_1.fastq.gz] [xERR1045146_2.fastq.gz]
[xERR1045148_1.fastq.gz] [xERR1045148_2.fastq.gz]
[xERR1045149_1.fastq.gz] [xERR1045149_2.fastq.gz]
[xERR1045151_1.fastq.gz] [xERR1045151_2.fastq.gz]
[xERR1045152_1.fastq.gz] [xERR1045152_2.fastq.gz]
[xERR1045154_1.fastq.gz] [xERR1045154_2.fastq.gz]
[xERR  45154_1.fastq.gz] [xERR  45154_2.fastq.gz]
```

to show that the names are being handled correctly.

Note that I've named the files `xERR*` so as not to clash with your own files. You should adjust the loop to handle your own files once you're satisfied it will work okay.

And, just as an aside, if you don't want to do anything except for those cases where *both* files exist, you can simply replace the "action" line with something like:

```
[[ -f "${file2}" ]] && doSomethingWith "${file1}" "${file2}"
```

This will bypass those where the `2` file is not a regular file.